# What is the difference between "this ref" and "ref this" when talking about C# 7.2 ref extension methods?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ref, c#-7.2

Consider the following extension methods:

```
public static void Toggle(this ref bool @bool) => @bool = !@bool;

public static void Toggle2(ref this bool @bool) => @bool = !@bool;
```

These simply toggle a ref boolean variable value. Testing:

```
class Foo
{
    private bool _flag;
    public void DoWork()
    {
        _flag.Toggle();
        Console.WriteLine(_flag);
        _flag.Toggle2();
        Console.WriteLine(_flag);
    }
}
```

We get:

```
True
False
```

The question: Is there any hidden difference in choosing one syntax or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. These are called **modifiers**, and their order in the specification is *not defined*.

You can read the section on method parameters in [C# Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction) here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#method-parameters

It lists out the different options and defines how they interact and mix, but says nothing about what order you must use.

Comment: They are exactly the same according to the language specification, but not according to Roslyn =)

Answer (score 4):

Nope, they're exactly the same, just as (now) you can write an interpolated verbatim string literal using either `$@` or `@$`.

Comment: Another thing to ask. When declaring a static async method, is there a difference between: public static async... vs public async static?

Comment: They are exactly the same according to the language specification, but not according to Roslyn =)

Comment: @taquion Could you explain a bit more? It seems like you may be alluding to some sort of well-hashed controversy or other (although your message is a tiny "signal" to analyze). In any case, can you elaborate for non-Roslyn experts such as myself?

Answer (score 0):

Although they're exactly the same according to the language specification. I have found a difference that has to do more to the compiler and that may be a compiler bug. The setup to reproduce this is with Visual Studio 2019. The bug may be in other compilers versions, I really did not research more about this.

If your language level is 7.2 or above, then both syntax work just the same way. However if your project is working with language level 7.0 or 7.1 then the following will compile:

```
struct S {}

static class Extensions
{
    static void M(this ref S s) {}
}
```

But if we change the order of the modifiers like here:

```
static class Extensions
{
    static void M(ref this S s) {}
}
```

You will get the following compiler error message:

> error CS8107: Feature 'ref extension methods' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.2 or greater.

The weird part is that although `static void M(this ref S s)` compiles, there is no way of consuming the method as an extension method of `S`:

`s.M()  //error CS8107 here`

But you are able to call the method using the traditional static syntax:

`Extensions.M(ref s)`

So, although there is no difference regarding the language specification, for those using the Roslyn compiler it is better to use `this ref` instead of `ref this` since that would be backwards compatible with 7.0 and 7.1 as long as the bug is there IMO

I reported [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13877) the lack of information about ref extensions methods for structs, and some other guy reported to [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/38486) the issue.

I am not marking this answer as THE answer since I thinke those of @Jon Skeet and @Joel Coehoorn are more accurate regarding the language. But I think this is useful info anyway

Comment: *"...It is better to use `this ref` instead of `ref this`"...* Hmm, really? Just based only on reading the excellent info in your message, I would lean the opposite way. To me, "[having] no way [to] consume the method as an extension method" seems categorically more serious than "backwards compatibil[ity] with 7.0 and 7.1." Where the former is both a bug and limitation in the language's domain of existential substance, compiler revision hiccups seem like an administrative backwater? Maybe since C# is so consistently reliable, I simply assumed everyone left the old versions for dead...